# Can't get HBase to connect to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase

EDIT: I was able to get this to work.  I created a tutorial to show how:
http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/5-How-to-use-HBase-Hadoop-Clustered.html

I can get HBase working just fine when I set the hbase-site.xml property:

```
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>file:///app/hbase/hbase/</value>
```

This works just fine, it stores the data in the directory as expected, however I want it to connect to my running hadoop instance now instead of using a local file.  I set it to

```
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
```

Instead of the local file and it will not work.  Is there some extra configuration I need to do on the hadoop side to support this?  Hadoop is running and using port 9000.

Here's my core-site.xml from hadoop:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Also here's the error when trying to do a "list" in hbase shell:

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
12/06/28 15:26:29 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
12/06/28 15:26:29 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode /hbase/master
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1021)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:580)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaConstructor.newInstanceDirect(JavaConstructor.java:275)
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.ConstructorInvoker.call(ConstructorInvoker.java:91)
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.ConstructorInvoker.call(ConstructorInvoker.java:178)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what distribution & version of hadoop and hbase that you are using?   Also, what mode are you running your cluster in: standalone?  Pseudo-distributed?  Disctributed?  Lastly, are you trying to connect to HBase from within the cluster or remotely from outside the cluster?

Comment: Are you able to run hadoop commands from shell. Check that first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hbase cannot find the zookeeper quorum, you have to set the hbase.zookeeper.quorum property in hbase-site.xml. Also check if classpath is set properly or not, check this doc out

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html#classpath

Answer (score 0):

I used the configuration suggested in http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#zookeeper
stop Ipatables and start hbase with root mode.

Answer (score 0):

there may be compatibility issue please check http://rajkrrsingh.blogspot.in/2013/11/hbase-compatibility-with-hadoop-2x.html